# checking every two adjacent elements in rows of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I'm new to coding in R, perhaps my question maybe too easy.

I have a matrix "data" of dimension 299*5992. Each element is either A1 or A2 
so I want to concentrate information of the matrix like this:

```
XD=matrix(,dim(data)[1],(dim(data)[2])/2 )
for ( i in dim(XD)[1])
{
  for (j in dim(XD)[2])
  {
    if (data[i,2*j]==data[i,2*j-1])
    {XD[i,j]=-1}
    else
    {XD[i,j]=1
    }
  }
}
```

So I have 2 questions:

1. How to do this more efficiently?
2. When I call an element like XD[1,1] I get NA  even though I'm
   sure that matrix data is loaded correctly.

Comment: You are **not** looping at all, both `i` and `j` take only one value, `dim(data)[.]`.

Comment: So the question is: if 2 adjacent values, row wise, are equal, `XD[i,j] <- -1` else `XD[i,j] <- 1`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with only one `sapply` loop.

Make up some data.

```
set.seed(1234)
data <- matrix(sample(c("A1", "A2"), 96, TRUE), 8)
```

And compute the matrix `XD`.

```
XD <- sapply(seq(1, ncol(data), by = 2), function(j){
  2*(data[, j] == data[, j + 1]) - 1
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches to make it:

- **Solution 1** (I believe this one is the more efficient one than the latter)

You can use first get logical value by comparing two adjacent columns and then shape it into the desired matrix, where `ifelse` is used:

```
M <- matrix(ifelse(data[,seq(ncol(data))%%2==1]==data[,seq(ncol(data))%%2==0],-1,1),
            nrow = nrow(data))
```

which gives

```
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16]
[1,]    1    1    1   -1    1   -1    1    1   -1     1     1     1     1    -1     1    -1
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1   -1    1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1     1     1
[3,]   -1   -1    1   -1    1    1    1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
[4,]   -1    1   -1    1    1   -1   -1    1    1    -1     1    -1    -1     1    -1     1
```

- **Solution 2**

Besides the solution by [@Rui Barradas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59175523/12158757), you can also use `sapply` along with `split.default` and `data.frame` as below

```
M <- sapply(split.default(data.frame(data,stringsAsFactors = F),rep(1:(dim(data)[2]/2),1,each=2)),
                          function(v) ifelse(v[1]==v[2],-1,1))
```

which gives

```
> M
      1  2  3  4 5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
[1,]  1  1  1 -1 1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1
[2,]  1  1  1  1 1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1
[3,] -1 -1  1 -1 1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
[4,] -1  1 -1  1 1 -1 -1  1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1
```

**DATA**

```
set.seed(1)
data <- matrix(sample(c("A1", "A2"), 128, TRUE), 4)
```